# How to install rst2man on windows

Tags: windows, encryption, prerequisites

I am trying to install the rst2man client for windows after recieveing this message:

```
'rest2man' not found, man page not installed.
```

This is a prerequisite to install https://github.com/bluss/git-remote-gcrypt which I will install later.
The only solution I have found was for Linux:
http://phaseportrait.blogspot.ca/2009/07/installing-docutils-for-mercurial.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MSYS2 (http://www.msys2.org/), both mingw32 and mingw64, have the docutils package, which contains rst2man. Both python2 and python3 versions are available.